# SQL Server: Maximum number of records to return

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have `RowCount` to set number of records to return or affect. But we need to set this each time before executing sql statement. I am looking a way to set this once my application started and so it affect all queries execute via my application.

**Update**

I want to achieve a trial version strategy with limited records! I don't want to mess with my actual code and wish somehow database restrict number of records return in result of any query! An alternative could be pass a parameter to each store-procedure but I really don't like this one and looking for some other strategy!

Comment: now why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well, I want to restrict my application to fetch specific number of records in specific mode...

Comment: That sounds dangerous - 6 months down the line, you're making some unrelated change to the application, which suddenly wants to update 25 rows. But elsewhere, you've set an application limit of 20, and now suddenly 5 rows aren't updated, but no error messages appear. 6 months further down the line, you start investigating why some updates don't seem to be working correctly...

Comment: @Damien I agree! in fact, I had part of such investigation! :) But, giving a trail version with limit of 1000 records! thats my basic purpose to achieve! any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the application language you are using, so I can't give you the code, but **make a wrapper function for a database connect**.  In this function, after you connect to the database, issue the `SET ROWCOUNT n`, make `n` a parameter and add any logic you need to make it variable. I do a similar thing with CONTEXT_INFO, I set it in my connection function.

Remember, you'll need to connect to the database everywhere in your application (use search and replace) using this wrapper function, and as a result, you'll always have the rowcount set.

Comment: this is going to be least solution! but in this way I have to change lot of code , regardless by find or replace! but it is risky and costly...

Answer (score 7):

You can parameterise TOP in your code for all commands

```
DECLARE @rows int
SET @row = ISNULL(@row, 2000000000)
SELECT TOP (@rows) ... FROM ..
```

You can have TOP defined globally for all your queries this way, say by wrapping or extending SQLCommand

SET ROWCOUNT is not a safe option: it affects intermediate result sets and has other unpredictable behaviour. And it's partially deprecated to ignored in I/U/D DML: [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

> Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server

Comment: I understand the consequence of using ROWCOUNT but in fact, I just affect select statement... anyhow! using top mean I need to change all my queries that I really don't want to do! I am looking for a database level parameter to achieve this!

Comment: @mqpasta: you said "We have RowCount to set number of records to return or affect." I assume "affect" meant delete, insert, update etc. There is no database level setting: that would be the one of the most stupid things ever. You can set it per connection with SET ROWCOUNT but this has *issues* as noted and won't achieve what you want correctly

Answer (score 0):

On application start up, reset `RowCount` by executing the following command:

```
command.CommandText = "SET ROWCOUNT 0;";
```

When the specific mode is activated, set the `RowCount` to the needed value by executing the following command:

```
command.CommandText = "SET ROWCOUNT " + rowCount + ";";
```

When the specific mode is deactivated, reset `RowCount` again.

---

Refer to [SET ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx)

Comment: I found it didn't work... it set just for specific command but not for all upcoming queries...